# Filezilla FTP error 550 for some files when uploading

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

I am in the middle of a web site maintenance when all of the sudden I notice that a few files can't be uploaded on the server, some of these files, I already uploaded them in the past in previous maintenance. I get an error 550 Access is denied
Here is the stack I have

```
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting upload of C:\production\wwws-20131223-1\www\www\maint\institution\Detail.aspx
Command:    CWD /*******/www/www/maint/institution
Response:   250 CWD command successful.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (*******).
Command:    STOR Detail.aspx
Response:   550 Access is denied.
```

I checked the rights on the server between a file I can change on these ones, same rights...

Any idea of what is wrong?
Thank you all.